# How to make a sed "script" restart matching instead of quitting ("repeat" instead of "quit" command)?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I apologize if this question has already been answered but I searched this site and several of its communities and could not find any information on this topic.

I frequently use this general `sed` command to print all lines from a line matching `STARTPAT` up to, but not including, a line matching `ENDPAT`:

```
sed -rn '/STARTPAT/,/ENDPAT/{/STARTPAT/{p;n};/ENDPAT/{q};p}' FILE
```

This cannot match multiple sections of `FILE`, however, because of the `q`uit command to prevent printing the second matching line (or, at least, I *think* this is the reason).

I would like to be able to apply this same concept **globally** but cannot get it to work properly. I have tried applying the `g`lobal command to different points at which patterns are matched as well as combined with the `p` and `n` commands, and I have also tried using methods of "storing" printed output to just print it all at the end (similar to using `sed` to print paragraphs containing a match). Maybe I am just not understanding how, exactly, the `g`lobal command, or ranges in general.

I have also been looking through the man page for `sed` and a few `sed` tutorials online in case there is already a built-in command for `sed` that behaves like `q` but instead of exiting, it repeats the provided "script" and forgets the previously-matched lines (so as not to skip a matching section that immediately follows another matching section, since the first match for that following section is the same line that was ignored in the previous match).

Let me know if any additional information would be helpful. Thanks in advance for any help I can get, even if I am way off base or am asking for something that just doesn't exist.

### **UPDATED BY REQUEST** [2019-Mar-11]:

Using the [original solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55095245/5465305) provided by [John1024](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3030305/john1024), the specific command I was attempting to construct is:

```
apt-cache depends --recurse --no-suggests --no-recommends --no-conflicts \
--no-breaks --no-replaces --no-enhances gdm3 | \
sed -rn '/^\S*(unity|ubuntu|desktop|session)/,/^\S+/{/^\S*(unity|ubuntu|desktop|session)/{p;n};/^\S+/d;p}'
```

Here is some example output:

```
  Depends: libxtst6
gnome-session
  Depends: gnome-settings-daemon
gnome-session-flashback
  Depends: dbus-user-session
    dbus-user-session:i386
  Depends: gnome-session-bin
  Depends: gnome-session-common
  Depends: gnome-settings-daemon
  Depends: indicator-common
  Depends: nautilus
  Depends: systemd
    systemd:i386
lxqt-session
  Depends: libc6
```

When I use the simplified solution provided by [John1024](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3030305/john1024):

```
apt-cache depends --recurse --no-suggests --no-recommends --no-conflicts \
--no-breaks --no-replaces --no-enhances gdm3 | \
sed -rn '/^\S*(unity|ubuntu|desktop|session)/,/^\S+/{/^\S+/d;p}'
```

the output does not contain *any* lines that match `/^\S+/`, which means no "top-level" dependency names are displayed, and some sets of dependencies that *should* be displayed are skipped entirely. Here is a snippet of the output, which would - ideally - match that of the previous example:

```
  Depends: libxtst6
  Depends: dbus-user-session
    dbus-user-session:i386
  Depends: gnome-session-bin
  Depends: gnome-session-common
  Depends: gnome-settings-daemon
  Depends: indicator-common
  Depends: nautilus
  Depends: systemd
    systemd:i386
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libglib2.0-0
  Depends: libgtk2.0-0
  Depends: libx11-6
  Depends: lsb-release
```

The pre-existing command I referenced in my original question, which I use as part of a bash function to extract the `Description` paragraph from the `apt-cache show` output of one or more packages, is:

```
apt-cache show ${pkg} | \
sed -rn '/^Description(-en)?/,/^[^: ]+:/{/^Description(-en)?/{p;n};/^[^: ]+:/{q};p}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are ok with `awk`, I am adding an `awk` variant here too.

```
awk '/ENDPAT/{flag=""}  /STARTPAT/{flag=1} flag'  Input_file
```

Taking example of Input_file which @John1024 has posted in his post.

```
cat Input_file
omit 1
STARTPAT
keep 1
ENDPAT
omit 2
STARTPAT
keep 2
ENDPAT
omit 3
```

After running code we will get following output.

```
awk '/ENDPAT/{flag=""}  /STARTPAT/{flag=1} flag'  Input_file
STARTPAT
keep 1
STARTPAT
keep 2
```

Comment: This also worked just as I needed but the person who first helped me learn `sed` had a weird, irrational dislike of `awk` for reasons I will never know so I'm biased towards `sed`. This did help me better understand some of the way `awk` functions so I still really appreciate the response!

Comment: This is actually the more correct answer. The solution using `sed` above actually drops quite a few lines that should be included in the command output. Thank you very much! I guess this is a time where awk might be the better choice.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
sed -rn '/STARTPAT/,/ENDPAT/{/STARTPAT/{p;n};/ENDPAT/d;p}' file
```

The difference here is that, instead of quitting (`q`) when `ENDPAT` is reached, we simply delete that unwanted line (`d`).

#### Example

Consider this test file:

```
$ cat file
omit 1
STARTPAT
keep 1
ENDPAT
omit 2
STARTPAT
keep 2
ENDPAT
omit 3
```

Let's run our command:

```
$ sed -rn '/STARTPAT/,/ENDPAT/{/STARTPAT/{p;n};/ENDPAT/d;p}' file
STARTPAT
keep 1
STARTPAT
keep 2
```

#### Simplification

```
$ sed -rn '/STARTPAT/,/ENDPAT/{/ENDPAT/d;p}' file
STARTPAT
keep 1
STARTPAT
keep 2
```

Comment: That is a creative, but straight-forward, solution to the problem if I understand the problem correctly.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you.

Comment: And, just a note, the simplified solution you provided does not quite behave as, *I think*, you intended because of my specific case. I am using this command to extract the name of each dependency that matches `STARTPAT` as well as all of that dependency's dependencies `apt-cache depends --recurse ...`, so your simplified solution actually deletes all of the direct dependency names because the way it deletes matches to `ENDPAT` (`^\S*`) also deletes matches to `STARTPAT` (e.g., `^\S*(NAME|OTHER|PKG|PACK)`)

Comment: `/STARTPAT/{p;n}` causes the STARTPAT line to be printed (`p`) and then skips the rest of the code and starts over from the beginning on a new line (`n`).  So, the lines that are processed by `/STARTPAT/{p;n}`  are __not__ fed to `/ENDPAT/d;p`.

Comment: Regarding the issues with the simplified solution, would you [edit] the question and add an update with the actual code that you are using.  Thanks.

Comment: @John1024 I updated the question with my specific use cases and provided some example output to help demonstrate my issue. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Upon closer inspection, I have realized that even the long-form `sed` command you provided loses about 100 lines that should actually be included in the output. I will try to update my question again tomorrow morning with some examples of what was missing.